# Is it worth installing java for a single application?

Tags: java, file-sharing, aerofs

I'd like to use [AeroFS](http://www.aerofs.com) as Windows Live Mesh is going away. I'm a heavy user of the PC-PC sync functionality and there's nothing similar available on the market.

BUT, AeroFS requires Java. So, in your opinionation is it worth it? I don't wear a tin foil hat, but Java is just a mess these days.

I've been searching for a while for a free alternative but haven't found something that works as well as Windows Live Mesh, but open to suggestions.

Comment: why are you trying to avoid java?

Comment: When homeland security warns about it just seems like one warning too many... http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/01/14/department-of-homeland-security-disable-java-unless-it-is-absolutely-necessary/

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no need **not** to install Java. Even though there are few common applications that require Java, you will always stumble upon something. You are not losing anything by having - it's like installing Flash or Silverlight.

If you are just concerned because the recent news that Java is not safe, that is actually just for Java Applets. And I don't know much about the website you want to use, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't involve these, because they are pretty rare now-a-days.

Anyway, it's just my opinion, but I don't think installing Java is problem. You can deactivate Java Applets very easily, just google it. In Firefox, for example, there is this article:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20turn%20off%20Java%20applets

But of course you can re-activate it any time for trusted web-sites, it's way easier than installing it all over again.

Comment: +1 for recommending disabling auto-running in browsers. This is highly recommended.

Answer (score -3):

A single java installer is pretty tame these days and fairly small. Just disable the automatic updates and you shouldn't have any nagging problems with it down the road.

Comment: Disabling auto updates is a potentially major security risk.

Comment: An appalling security risks given the issues Java has had over the last few years

Comment: Agree that this does not seem like the way to go...